# One to Many search using AND condition

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have the following product which contain many colors.

I wish to find the product which contain at least RED and GREEN.

```
Product class

    String id;

    List<Color> colors{};

Color class

    id

    color

kindly ignore the syntax error.
```

I'm able to use the following to search OR condition.

```
Criteria criteria = createCriteria();
criteria.createAlias("colors","colors");

List<String> colorsList = new LinkedList();
colorsList.add("GREEN");
colorsList.add("RED");
criteria.add(Restriction.in("colors.color",colorsList);
```

The above will give me products which has red or green in their colors BUT not products which contain at least RED AND GREEN.

Example

```
Product: RED GREEN - PASS
Product: RED GREEN YELLOW - PASS
Product: RED YELLOW - FAIL
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean that you need all products that has red and green colors and the same product but it has different color. (in another word, you don't need any product that hasn't red and green letter). that's true?

Comment: yup. example: Product Green Red Yellow will be shown

Answer (score 2):

the idea is we select all products with the colors and count each product, then products with both colors should have a count of 2 as the number of colors

```
DetachedCriteria colorCrit = DetachedCriteria.For(Product.class)
    .createAlias("colors","color")
    .add(Restriction.eq("color.color", "RED")
    .add(Restriction.eq("color.color", "GREEN")
    .SetProjection(Projections.Group("id"))
    .add(Restriction.eq(Projections.rowCount(), 2));

Criteria criteria = createCriteria()
    .add(Subqueries.in("id", colorCrit)
    .list();
```

**Update:**

there is an [issue](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-1043?focusedCommentId=35459&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%253Acomment-tabpanel#action_35459) for hibernate for exactly this. the last comment describes how to use.

Comment: looks good, but is there another way? that seems too much work just for a simple search? =x the search function accept a list of criterions only, I don't wish to change that function unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: try to come up with a sql-query that does this and i will happily translate it to criteria. if you would have a backreference in the color then you could do a "subqueries.eq(colors.count(), subqueryWhereBackreferenceEqualThisAlias"

Comment: is there anyway to avoid subqueries for this condition? I have been trying the whole day but I can't avoid the use of subqueries too.

Comment: colorCrit >> just curious, is this an independent query, It seems to be but I just want to confirm

Comment: i can't think of a sql without a subquery and yes colorCrit is independent

Comment: .add(Restriction.eq(Projections.rowCount(), 2)); >> this doesn't not work.. because Projection.rowCOunt() is not a property.

Comment: Projection.count("color") . Restriction.eq should have an overload which takes a projection.

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html  -> Nope it does not.

Comment: i assumed that NHibernate and Hibernate are equal there. then you have to follow the link i posted and use the having implementation there

Comment: Thanks Firo but sadly I am not allowed to modify the API

Comment: which API? it is just a new class to add to your project and instead of `Projections.Group("foo")` you'll use `new GroupByHavingProjection("foo", Projections.count("bar"), "=", 2));`