# Select at least A and B from one to many table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a product table with a relationship to color table

a product can have many colors... 
exp: Product A: has red, green blue yellow.

How may I select products which contain at least red and green(dynamic)?

example:

```
Product: RED GREEN - PASS
Product: RED GREEN YELLOW - PASS
Product: RED YELLOW - FAIL
```

Prefer join table solution or independent sub queries only

this problem is related to 
[One to Many search using AND condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409302/one-to-many-search-using-and-condition/11411560#comment15060477_11411560)

I'm trying to tackle it from fundamentals.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
SELECT product.name
  FROM product
       JOIN color USING (product_id)
 WHERE color.name IN ('red', 'green')
 GROUP BY product.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT color.name) = 2
```

where the `HAVING` clause specifies the number of items in the list.  So if you wanted products that are available in red, green, and yellow, you'd change the query to

```
SELECT product.name
  FROM product
       JOIN color USING (product_id)
 WHERE color.name IN ('red', 'green', 'yellow')
 GROUP BY product.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT color.name) = 3
```